# Parse.com - Push duplicated after reinstall app

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

Good afternoon.

I'm facing a problem that I've researched, but didn't find a solution.

I'm using Parse.com Push in my Android app. When a push is sent, I receive the same message many times. It's duplicated in Data Browser too.

At first, I'd thought that it was my fault. But I think that an older installation must not affect a new one.

Can you help me, please?

Thank you.

Comment: I use this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28050986/how-to-avoid-installation-duplicates-using-parse/33306713#33306713

Answer (score 0):

The solution given [**here**](https://www.parse.com/questions/check-for-duplicate-installations-of-same-user-on-re-installation-of-app) by Mukul should help.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if Parse.com has an official solution? Regards.

Comment: Unfortunately, they do not.

Comment: Thank you. I`ve posted a bug and a question in their site.

Comment: Great! I have subscribed to the bug as we are facing this issue too

Comment: any news on that for those without facebook account?