# How to avoid Installation duplicates using Parse?

Tags: android, parse-platform, installation

I've noticed that every time I've deployed my app to my phone,it duplicates the installation in parse to receive push notifications. How can I avoid this from happening whenever I reinstall the app?

Comment: We need a lot more information. What's the packageName? Are you using Gradle? If so, post the relevant build.gradle files.

Comment: I am using the Eclipse IDE

Comment: Still need a lot more information... What do you mean by "duplicate the installation"? Duplicate applications? So another `packageName`?

Comment: I edited my post,by installation I'm referring to the Parse API. Not the application install itself.

Comment: Maybe is because every reinstall has a different hashkey that Parse use to know is the installation and dispositive are the same, when this condition isn't equal the Parse API makes a new installation not a duplicate.

Comment: Should I try a beforeSave in CloudCode to delete the previous installation of the user?

Answer (score 3):

After a week of research and try and error, I finally found a working solution. Basically, you need to do two things to achieve this:

- **In your Android app:** pass some unique ID when you initialize and save the `ParseInstallation`.  we will use [ANDROID_ID](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID).
- **In Parse Cloud Code:** Before you save a new `Installation`, check to see if its unique ID exist in an old `Installation`. If it does, delete the old one.

---

**How To Do it:**

- In the `onCreate()` method of your Application:

  ```
  //First: get the ANDROID_ID
  String android_id = Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
  Parse.initialize(this, "APP_ID", "CLIENT_KEY");
  //Now: add ANDROID_ID value to your Installation before saving.
  ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().put("androidId", android_id);
  ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
  ```
- In your cloud code, add this:

  ```
  Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.Installation, function(request, response) {
      Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
      var androidId = request.object.get("androidId");
      if (androidId == null || androidId == "") {
          console.warn("No androidId found, save and exit");
          response.success();
      }
      var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
      query.equalTo("androidId", androidId);
      query.addAscending("createdAt");
      query.find().then(function(results) {
          for (var i = 0; i < results.length; ++i) {
              console.warn("iterating over Installations with androidId= "+ androidId);
              if (results[i].get("installationId") != request.object.get("installationId")) {
                  console.warn("Installation["+i+"] and the request have different installationId values. Try to delete. [installationId:" + results[i].get("installationId") + "]");
                  results[i].destroy().then(function() {
                      console.warn("Installation["+i+"] has been deleted");
                  },
                  function() {
                      console.warn("Error: Installation["+i+"] could not be deleted");
                  });
              } else {
                  console.warn("Installation["+i+"] and the request has the same installationId value. Ignore. [installationId:" + results[i].get("installationId") + "]");
              }
          }
          console.warn("Finished iterating over Installations. A new Installation will be saved now...");
          response.success();
      },
      function(error) {
          response.error("Error: Can't query for Installation objects.");
      });
  });
  ```

And that's it!

---

**Things you might want to know:**

- There is no *perfect* unique identifier for Android devices. In my case, I used [ANDROID_ID](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID). You might use something else. [Read this official article](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html?_sm_au_=iVVM4VFpvD64SJ62) to get a better picture.
- Note that after calling `put("androidId", android_id);` for the first time, a new column named `androidId` will be added to your `Installation` table view in the Parse App Dashboard.

---

Resources: [[1](https://www.parse.com/questions/check-for-duplicate-installations-of-same-user-on-re-installation-of-app)], [[2](https://gist.github.com/mbmc/ebe5b65bc4eb86904c78)], [[3](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Query.html)]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone trying to attempt this with React Native (and Expo)... I've written this routine to help with Installation duplication issues. Its purely client-side but seems to work well in conjunction with Cloud Code duplication checks.

```
import Parse from 'parse/react-native.js';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import * as Application from 'expo-application';
import * as Localization from 'expo-localization';

export const currentInstallationAsync = async (): Parse.Installation => {
    const installationId = await Parse._getInstallationId();
    console.log(`installationId: ${installationId}`);

    return new Parse.Installation({
        installationId,
        appName: Application.applicationName,
        appVersion: Application.nativeApplicationVersion,
        deviceType: Platform.OS,
        localeIdentifier: Localization.locale,
        timeZone: Localization.timezone,
        appIdentifier: Application.applicationId,
    });
}
```